# Resolving a question that has an out-of-scope solution

Tags: discussion, self-answer

Suppose I ask a question about my software misbehaving and get a few answers and comments that don't resolve it. Then I discover that, say, my host system does modifications and upgrades on Tuesdays and what I thought was broken is perfectly fine

How should I leave my question? Should I delete it, answer it myself in terms that no one will find useful, or leave it unanswered?

The real-life instance of this is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31566796/selecting-first-text-child-node)

Comment: I would just close as "off topic" > "cannot be reproduced / typo".  Deletion is a personal preference.

Comment: Either: 1. edit the question to have given someone enough information to answer it (e.g. specify the library) and write an answer; or 2. delete it. I don't see any point in leaving it hanging around in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

Because, the problem stated in question is never going to be reproduced (As this is some host system issue) so I think vote to close as off-topic-cannot be reproduced is the perfect term for this.

Or If you want to be more specific then Add self answer and describe the resolution.

If you think, this question is not going to help community in any how, you can delete it, **but its totally individual choice**.

As per [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions)

> Users can delete their own questions if the question:
>
> has zero answers OR only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes
>
> Simply click the delete link underneath the question.